# Compare two values in dictionarys python

Tags: python, api, dictionary, flask, compare

Pretty new to the python language and ran in to a problem.
Is it possible to compare values in dictionaries?

I've made two api calls and need to check if the id:s are same and then return all deals

My code:

```
    company_response = get_api_data(headers=headers, url=url)

    
    company_deals = get_api_data(headers=headers, url=url)

    

    myDealsDict = {}
    companyDict = {}
```

```
if len(company_response and company_deals) > 0:
        
        for company in company_response:
            companyDict[company['_id']] = company

        for deal in company_deals:
            try:
                myDealsDict[deal['company']]['deals'].append(deal)
            except KeyError:
                myDealsDict[deal['company']] = {
                    'company_name': companyDict[deal['company']],
                    'deals': [deal]
                }

        return render_template("api.html", allDeals=myDealsDict)
```

allDeals only return the id:s of the companies now..

EDIT Sample:

```
Companies
    "id": 0,
    "name": "string",
    "phone": "string",
    "www": "string",
    "postaladdress1": "string",
    "visitingaddress1": "string",
    "postaladdress2": "string",
    "visitingaddress2": "string",
    "postalzipcode": "string",
    "postalcity": "string",
    "visitingzipcode": "string",
    "visitingcity": "string",
    "country": "string",
    "fullpostaladdress": "string",
    "fullvisitingaddress": "string",
    "debitorno": 0,
    "inactive": true,
    "prisfil": true,
    "registrationno": "string",
    "coworker": 0,

Deals:
     [
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "string",
    "company": 0,
    "person": 0,
    "coworker": 0,
    "dealstatus": {
      "id": 0,
      "key": "contact",
      "text": "string"
    },
    "value": "string",
    "probability": "string",
    "weightedvalue": "string",
    "wonlostreason": "string",
    "quotesent": "2022-03-21",
    "expecteddate": "string",
    "closeddate": "2022-03-21",
    "todo2": 0
  }
]
```

Need to compare the company value in deals with company id.

Comment: please provide a sample of the relevant variables

Comment: can u provide a sample of the input and needed output?

Answer (score 0):

It looks from the above like you should be able to check if the value of `deal['id']` is in `companyDict` (i.e., in its keys).

When you use `in` with a Python dictionary, it checks the keys of the dictionary. And if I'm reading the above correctly, your keys will be the id numbers of the company.

```
for deal in company_deals:
    if deal['id'] in companyDict:
        <...other stuff here...>
```

Comment: You're welcome! Feel free to accept the answer as the solution if you have a moment.